# Выбор каталога для параметров сетевой конфигурации

Tags: oracle, клиент, sqlplus

На машине установлено несколько клиентов Oracle (с 8-й по 11-ю).  Последним был установлен клиент в каталог *ora10*. Когда выполняю соединение при помощи `sqlplus` к БД, считываются параметры из *tnsnames.ora* файла в подкаталоге каталогa *ora10*.

Как поменять путь к файлу *tnsnames.ora* на другой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При установке нескольких клиентов рекомендуеся файлы сетевой конфигурации (.ora) поместить в отдельный каталог (в любой, доступный для чтения/записи), и создать переменную окружения `TNS_ADMIN` указываюшую на этот каталог.
Подробнее о [TNS_ADMIN Parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntqrf/about-tns-admin-parameter.html#GUID-7EE1F936-F108-4575-941C-63E0011B0CC0):

> You can add the parameter TNS_ADMIN to change the directory path of Oracle Net Services configuration files from the default location of *ORACLE_HOME\network\admin*.
>
> For example, if you set `TNS_ADMIN` to *ORACLE_HOME\test\admin*, then the configuration files are used from *ORACLE_HOME\test\admin*.

---

Замечание об установке нескольких клиентов на одну машину [Multiple Oracle Home Components](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntcli/multiple-oracle-home-components.html#GUID-AB09CFF1-64FE-4B07-874C-BD2CACBC15F8):

> You can install all Oracle components in multiple Oracle homes on the same computer.
>
> However, some components can only support one active instance at a time. **The current (latest) installation renders the previous one inactive**.

Oracle не предоставляет документированного способа переключения между установленными версиями клиента. Поэтому, использовать старые версии на одной машине скорее всего имеет мало смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо изменить или задать значение переменной окружения `ORACLE_HOME`.
Так же, при наличии нескольких клиентов, надо смотреть SQLPlus какого клиента запускается.Если адрес не задан явно, то будет выбран первый найденый при обходе переменной `Path`(проверка идет слева на право). При отсутствии переменной `ORACLE_HOME` SQLplus идет смотреть в tnanames.ora в папке для своей версии по умолчанию.

Comment: Я не нашел такой переменной в "переменные окружения", а в реестре у меня есть ORACLE_HOME для каждой из версий оракла. Что именно мне надо поменять? Система под Windows. В командной строке `set oracle_home`,в ответ получаю сообщение о том, что переменная не определена

Comment: приколько, то есть у вас в ветке HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Oracle три раза Oracle прописан?

Comment: Внутри Oracle есть много подкаталогов по версиям. Дополните ответ, что надо поменять или ОркалХом или значение переменной Path

Comment: Изменение значение переменной Path боюсь вам не поможет, посколько программа полезет в систему смотреть куда установлен Oracle а при установке последнего клиента он у вас явно перезатер переменную. Попробуйте поискать программу Oracle  Home Selector тогда...

Comment: Я уже решил проблему. 5 установленных клиентов предполагает 5 sqplus'ов. Последний установленный клиент дописал в PATH слева путь к sqlplus от Оракла 10 версии. И по этому по умолчанию из командной строки запускался он и соответственно лез в каталоги десятки. Изменение PATH привело к запуску другой версии sqlplus который полез в другие каталоги за tns

Comment: Поздравляю, я почему то считал что он полезет сначало смотреть значение oracle_home

Comment: повторюсь, oracle_home просто нет. Совсем нет, никак нет

Comment: Я это понял....вот я и удивлен